# How can I implement 'finding min-spanning tree algorithm' on a complex graph using graph-viz?

Tags: linux

I need to find minimum spanning trees in a large graph using graph-viz. The number of nodes and edge information will be given in another text-file in 2 columns,"source" and "destination". please help.

Answer (score 1):

Graphviz is principally a tool to layout graphs. The algorithms that are included relate to this task. The input for a graph is a graph specification.

What you need is a tool that computes the MST. There are several. The wikipedia article is a good start for references:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim's_algorithm

In python there is

http://pygraphviz.github.io/

In perl, I found

https://gist.github.com/hirotnk/780342

The SO answer here:

[Graphviz Dot Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245350/graphviz-dot-algorithm)

is also a good reference.

Given the output of an MST tool, you can general a file that is rendered by graphviz.